# Reference for light interaction with many electron atoms

Tags: quantum-mechanics, atomic-physics, resource-recommendations, radiation, computational-physics

I am trying to understand light interaction with  many electron atoms.
I know that to calculate the bound states  we can use Hartree-Fock method but for light interaction with matter i do not know it this method works.

I am searching for references and open source programs.
Could anyone help me please?

Comment: There is Bob Cowan's computer program: https://www.tcd.ie/Physics/people/Cormac.McGuinness/Cowan/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When atoms and molecules interact with electromagnetic radiation, there could be some transitions between rotational, vibrational or electronic states. Whenever electronic transitions happens, the Coulomb interaction is changed due to the redistribution of the electrons.

Hartree-Fock deals with the stationary states of many-electron systems, and do not describe the response to a time-dependent perturbation, like the electric field of an EM wave. Thus, you can not calculate dynamical properties nor atomic or molecular spectra using only Hartree-Fock, you need Time-Dependent Hartree-Fock. However, the HF method does not consider Coulomb correlation, so it is better to use Time-Dependent Density Functional Theory with an appropriate exchange-correlation functional to calculate molecular spectra more quantitatively.

There are many quantum chemistry/solid-state programs that incorporate the TDDFT scheme. For instance, [Gaussian16](http://gaussian.com/) program includes TDDFT and also TDHF, but the software is too expensive. Nonetheless, there are programs like [NWChem](http://www.nwchem-sw.org/index.php/Main_Page) and [DIRAC](http://www.diracprogram.org/doku.php?id=start) that have implemented the TDDFT scheme and have open access.

To read about the fundamentals of TDHF or TDDFT, I would recommend this two books:

- [Methods of Molecular Quantum Mechanics](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0124865526) by R. McWeeny. This book contains the basics of electronic structure from HF theory to intermolecular interactions, passing through multiconfiguration theories, perturbation theory, linear response theory, and propagator and equation of motion methods. Chapter 12 has some sections about TDHF.
- [Time-Dependent Density-Functional Theory](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0199563020) by C. Ullrich. It is a book dedicated exclusively to TDDFT. It contains the basic formalism of TDDFT and linear response theory and further developments. Also, Appendix O have a list with another popular computer codes which include TDDFT.

Comment: For atomic spectra, one does not need explicitly time-dependent calculations. It is enough to compute the matrix elements between initial and final states.